# Git push results in return code 22

Tags: git, apache, ubuntu, centos, ldap

I've gone through related questions on here and nothing has worked for me.

I'm trying to setup git with LDAP authentication through Apache. The authentication works and I can clone. But when I try to push I get "return code 22."

I have tried on both CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 16.04. Both are updated.

The client system is Windows 10 and the latest version from git-scm.com.

I'm guessing there's an issue with my Apache conf.

Here's how I created the git directory

```
git init --bare /var/www/html/git/gitrepo.git
cd /var/www/html/git/gitrepo.git
mv hooks/post-update.sample  hooks/post-update
chmod a+x  hooks/post-update
git update-server-info
```

Here's my apache conf:

```
LDAPSharedCacheSize 500000
LDAPCacheEntries 1024
LDAPCacheTTL 600
LDAPOpCacheEntries 1024
LDAPOpCacheTTL 600
LDAPVerifyServerCert Off

<Directory "/var/www/html/git">
   Options +ExecCGI
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   AcceptPathInfo On
   DocumentRoot  "/var/www/html/git"
   ServerName git.site.domain.com
   DirectoryIndex index.html

   SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/html/git
   SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
   SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
   ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} service=git-receive-pack [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /git-receive-pack$ 
   RewriteRule ^/git/ - [E=AUTHREQUIRED:yes]


    <LocationMatch "/">

        Options +ExecCGI
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "site.domain.com"
        AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative on
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=LDAP_User,CN=Users,DC=site,DC=domain,DC=com"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "password"
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://dc.site.domain.com/dc=site,dc=domain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?Sub?(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)"
        AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
        Require valid-user

    </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here's the client config in .git:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://192.168.16.147/gitrepo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I used GIT_CURL_VERBOSE and it shows the authentication works initially but then fails after a propfind:

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push origin master
* Couldn't find host git.site.domain.com in the _netrc file; using defaults
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 192.168.16.147...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to git.site.domain.com (192.168.16.147) port 80 (#0)
> GET /gitrepo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: git.site.domain.com
User-Agent: git/2.12.2.windows.2
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Wed, 26 Apr 2017 19:27:03 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="site.domain.com"
< Content-Length: 381
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<
* Connection #0 to host git.site.domain.com left intact
* Couldn't find host git.site.domain.com in the _netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host git.site.domain.com: 0x290be50 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host git.site.domain.com
* Connected to git.site.domain.com (192.168.16.147) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'bobsaget'
> GET /gitrepo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: git.site.domain.com
Authorization: Basic encryptedstring
User-Agent: git/2.12.2.windows.2
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 26 Apr 2017 19:27:03 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
< Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Apr 2017 18:11:35 GMT
< ETag: "0-54e01a77ac500"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
<
* Connection #0 to host git.site.domain.com left intact
* Couldn't find host git.site.domain.com in the _netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host git.site.domain.com: 0x290be50 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host git.site.domain.com
* Connected to git.site.domain.com (192.168.16.147) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'bobsaget'
> GET /gitrepo.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1
Host: git.site.domain.com
Authorization: Basic encryptedstring
User-Agent: git/2.12.2.windows.2
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 26 Apr 2017 19:27:07 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
< Last-Modified: Mon, 24 Apr 2017 20:51:42 GMT
< ETag: "17-54defc6469818"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 23
<
* Connection #0 to host git.site.domain.com left intact
* Couldn't find host git.site.domain.com in the _netrc file; using defaults
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 192.168.16.147...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to git.site.domain.com (192.168.16.147) port 80 (#0)
> PROPFIND /gitrepo.git/ HTTP/1.1
Host: git.site.domain.com
User-Agent: git/2.12.2.windows.2
Accept: */*
Depth: 0
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 172
Expect: 100-continue

* The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
error: Cannot access URL http://git.site.domain.com/gitrepo.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://git.site.domain.com/gitrepo.git'
```

Apache error log shows successful authentication but fails without making a second attempt:

```
[Wed Apr 26 15:27:07.177075 2017] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 32543] mod_authnz_ldap.c(501): [client 192.168.16.216:54725] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://192.168.16.222/dc=site,dc=domain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?Sub?(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)
[Wed Apr 26 15:27:07.177094 2017] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 32543] mod_authnz_ldap.c(593): [client 192.168.16.216:54725] AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting bobsaget
[Wed Apr 26 15:27:07.177100 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32543] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.16.216:54725] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : granted
[Wed Apr 26 15:27:07.177104 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32543] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.16.216:54725] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Wed Apr 26 15:27:07.227516 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32548] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.16.216:54728] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)
[Wed Apr 26 15:27:07.227564 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 32548] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 192.168.16.216:54728] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
```

EDIT: I added "AcceptPathInfo On" to my httpd.conf and checked the environment variables needed according to git help http-backend are set.

I also added the rewrite conditions used there. Updated the configuration above accordingly.

Comment: Jeff seems to have nailed the answer: http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg302317.html

Comment: Yes. He's replied to me there. I don't have a solution yet though as the modules are loaded and everything looks fine according to the git help http-backend.

Answer (score 2):

So, thanks to the git mailing list we identified an error in my configuration.

The DocumentRoot needs to be "/var/www/html".

In case it is useful for someone else this is my conf that is so far working:

```
LDAPSharedCacheSize 500000
LDAPCacheEntries 1024
LDAPCacheTTL 600
LDAPOpCacheEntries 1024
LDAPOpCacheTTL 600
LDAPVerifyServerCert Off

<Directory "/var/www/html/git">
   Options +ExecCGI
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   AcceptPathInfo On
   DocumentRoot  "/var/www/html"
   ServerName git.site.domain.com
   DirectoryIndex index.html

   SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/html/git
   SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
   SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
   ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} service=git-receive-pack [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /git-receive-pack$ 
   RewriteRule ^/git/ - [E=AUTHREQUIRED:yes]


    <LocationMatch "/">

        Options +ExecCGI
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "site.domain.com"
        AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative on
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=LDAP_User,CN=Users,DC=site,DC=domain,DC=com"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "password"
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://dc.site.domain.com/dc=site,dc=domain,dc=com?sAMAccountName?Sub?(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)"
        AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
        Require valid-user

    </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```